# How can i apply logistic regression algorithm to plot decision boundry using moons data

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I know this has been asked before, but my question is slightly different. I want to use scikit-learn's moons data for my task and couldn't find a way to do it.
My task is clear:

Firstly, i want to load scikit-learn's moons dataset and Split dataset such that randomly selected 70% tuples are used for training while 30% tuples
are used for testing.

I used this code to do it:

How can i edit my code to do the task i want? Can you help me figuring it out?

Answer (score 1):

You have 100 points in `X`, so when you write `X[100:,0]`, it selects all the points starting at 100, which returns an empty array.

you want to write:

```py
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:, 1], c=y, ...)
```